# Asp.Net MVC RoutConfig.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Welcome!I used in the project area. I can not understand why not let the area. When the correct link is loaded home page. I want to to achieve the following: I have a project in the field of HomeController.
If you change the name of the controller in the field on StartController it works. I want to have 2 HomeControllers. 
What's wrong with being routed. Add namespace for AdminAreaRegistration.cs tried, does not work

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "lang",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { lang = @"ru|en" },
            namespaces: new[] { "ModelAgency.Client.WebUI.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, lang = "ru" },
            namespaces: new[] { "ModelAgency.Client.WebUI.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

AdminAreaRegistration.cs

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            //namespaces: new [] { "ModelAgency.Client.WebUI.Areas.Admin.Controllers" } tried, does not work
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add controller="Home",  all exactly directs Home
Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }




 public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
            {
                public override string AreaName
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return "Admin";
                    }
                }


                public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
                {
                    context.MapRoute(
                        "Admin_default",
                        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                    );
                }
            }
```